# Django Unhandled Exception

Tags: python, django

It is running under DEBUG = True mode. Sometimes it can throw out an error message with traceback information when encounter an error but sometimes it just display the following lines:

```
Unhandled Exception

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
```

I have to switch to development server to see detail message.

How can I make it always display traceback message when an error is encountered?

Comment: So the displaying of the error is not consistent, is there any pattern to what errors are shown and what aren't?

Comment: How are you serving the site? You say below Nginx, but is it FastCGI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can use this snippet, this will log exceptions in apache's log:

`utils.py`:

```
def log_traceback(exception, args):
    import sys, traceback, logging
    exceptionType, exceptionValue, exceptionTraceback = sys.exc_info()
    logging.debug(exception)
    logging.debug(args)
    for tb in traceback.format_exception(exceptionType, exceptionValue, exceptionTraceback):
        logging.debug(tb)
```

`site_logging.py`:

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Put it in your `settings.py` :

```
import site_logging
```

And in your code:

```
from where.is.your.utils import log_traceback
try:
   `do something`
except Exception, args:
    log_traceback(Exception, args)
```

Answer (score 10):

Just connect to the got_request_exception signal and log the exception:

```
from django.core.signals import got_request_exception
import logging    

def log(*args, **kwargs):
    logging.exception('error')

got_request_exception.connect(log)
```

This will log the whole trace. In the dev server, it logs in the console.

Comment: By default, all uncaught exceptions are already logged into the `django.request`.  The default logging setting is to propagate that to the `django` handler which will output to the console if `DEBUG` is True or email the admins if `DEBUG` is False.  If you want to change that, modify the `LOGGING` settings.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Apache?
Just out of interest is this your Production or Dev environment where you want to see the traceback?

From the [DJango Book on security - Exposed error messages](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter20/)

*Users deploying under Apache and mod_python should also make sure they have PythonDebug Off in their Apache conf files; this will ensure that any errors that occur before Django’s had a chance to load won’t be displayed publicly.*

I assume you want PythonDebug On, this is recommended for Development only.

Comment: i'm using mod_python with PythonDebug Off and i can still switch DEBUG = True in my settings to quickly troubleshoot an issue. It still gives me the handy django debug page instead of apache's 500 internal server error page.

Comment: sorry Jack, haven't used Nginx, so maybe someone with Nginx might be able to help trouble shoot. Brandon - could this be a Nginx specific?

Answer (score 1):

That's what DEBUG=True is for: to show the full traceback. The idea is that regular users do not want (nor do you want them to) see anything other than a simple error message.

Comment: There are certain errors that occur outside the 500-debug-page handling, where you still get a raw error from the webserver.

Comment: Yep, I've noticed too that sometimes I get mod_python error pages rather than the Django page.