# With DEBUG=False, how can I log django exceptions to a log file

Tags: django, error-handling, django-settings

With DEBUG=True, Django exceptions dump to stderr, which is typically sent to a rotating log file by the web server.

With DEBUG=False, Django instead emails the exception to the the ADMINS=.

How can I retain the DEBUG=True behavior with DEBUG=False?

I've read [How do you log server errors on django sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238081/how-do-you-log-server-errors-on-django-sites) and [How can I see error logs of Django views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125080/how-can-i-see-error-logs-of-django-views) and [How do you log server errors on django sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238081/how-do-you-log-server-errors-on-django-sites). The answer seems to involve some middleware.  Is there a code snippet available, or are these batteries included?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a full working logging configuration. Critical errors are logged to sentry, warnings are sent to admins by emails, normal notice errors are logged to syslog, and debug messages are prompted on the standard output.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[contactor] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        # Send all messages to console
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        # Send info messages to syslog
        'syslog':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            'facility': SysLogHandler.LOG_LOCAL2,
            'address': '/dev/log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        # Warning messages are sent to admin emails
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        },
        # critical errors are logged to sentry
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # This is the "catch all" logger
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'syslog', 'mail_admins', 'sentry'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a stderr logger option in there somewhere?

Comment: The [logging.StreamHandler class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) default output is stderr.

Comment: So if I checked propagate to True, I'd get the DEBUG=True behavior of logging via Apache?

Comment: You might want to check the [DEBUG entry in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG). It has few to do with logging. The [logging doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) is also very helpful.

Comment: @ThibaultJ "are prompted on the standard output." where is this standard output you referring to ? :) I am using DigitalOceam, Gunicorn and nginx

Comment: @Matthew I don't know. Better check the specific doc of DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 22):

Django uses a logging filter to decide wither the `console` handler is used or not by default. See also [django.utils.log on Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.2/django/utils/log.py#L38).

To keep the same behavior without filtering messages to console, just disable filtering in your `settings.py` like this:

```
from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING

DEFAULT_LOGGING['handlers']['console']['filters'] = []
```

Comment: where can I find the log files after adding this into the settings.py ?

Comment: Adding this to `settings.py` causes Django to send errors to stderr/stdout. Where this is logged depends on your webserver.

Comment: Amazing solution!

Comment: excellent solution, though monkey-patching's django might be frowned upon by some. One could use the following instead

LOGGING = deepcopy(DEFAULT_LOGGING)
DEFAULT_LOGGING['handlers']['console']['filters'] = []

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way of doing it with complexity half-way between the other answers, logs both to console and file

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
       'file': {
           'level': 'DEBUG',
           'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
           'filename': 'log.django',
       },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console','file'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: is there any way to filter logs, like only server error?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the minimal valid Django `LOGGING` configuration snippet required to log exception tracebacks to stderr.

Put this at the end of your `settings.py`:

```py
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {"handlers": ["console"], "level": "INFO"},
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExeptBot](https://exceptbot.com) for a log stored in your database and accessible within your site.  A plus is it hooks into ChatGPT to give you quick suggestions for how to fix the exceptions.

To add it to your site:

1. Install the ExceptBot library

```bash
pip3 install exceptbot
```

2. Add 'ExceptBot' to INSTALLED_APPS in your project's `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'exceptbot',
    # ...
]
```

3. Include the middleware in the MIDDLEWARE list in your `settings.py`:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'exceptbot.middleware.ExceptBotMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

4. Include the ExceptBot URLs in your project's `urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
  # ...
  path('', include('exceptbot.urls')),
  # ...
]
```

Run migrations to create the necessary database tables and set up static files

```bash
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations exceptbot
$ python3 manage.py migrate exceptbot
$ python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```