# Setting Debug=False on localhost makes the app crash and there's no way to find out what the error is

Tags: python, django

After changing `Debug=True` to `False` the app started to crash on localhost. And there's no way to find out what causes the error, because there's no error text being shown anywhere: neither in the browser, no in the terminal. That's it.

In `setting.py` I do have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`, by the way.

Django 1.8, python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your settings.py to see your error :

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[contactor] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        # Send all messages to console
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # This is the "catch all" logger
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

More info on logging configuration [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#configuring-logging).

Also, you can have a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289925/with-debug-false-how-can-i-log-django-exceptions-to-a-log-file).