# Django - CSS File Not Loading In Production (Debug: False)

Tags: python, django, server

Current error (Debug=False)

"[16/Jan/2018 15:18:42] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 90"

Web site loads but broken formatting because CSS file not loaded

Logging:

On the CMD prompt it says

```
"[16/Jan/2018 15:49:05] "GET /beginners/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3760
[16/Jan/2018 15:49:05] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 90
"
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working: my style.css is located in my static folder, and the static folder is the same folder as manage.py

When I set Debug = True, I reload the page and it works fine - my static folder is active and I get no static error:

```
[16/Jan/2018 15:58:11] "GET /beginners/? HTTP/1.1" 200 3759
[16/Jan/2018 15:58:11] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5014
```

Please help!!

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: How are you running the server? is it with manage.py runserver? When debug is False, django will not serve static content. You need use a webserver to serve your static files

Comment: @at14 Yes with manage.py, Oh I did not nkow that..wow...thanks,

Comment: @at14 add this to answer and I will give u best answr

Comment: Implement this code inside your project: Visit this link: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132733/how-run-static-file-when-debug-is-false>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using Django's development server with Debug=False. Django will not serve static content when Debug is False.

Django development server is not intended to be used in production.

You will need a Web Server which will serve your static content (or put it on a CDN)

Common deployment styles used with Django are

nginx -> uwsgi -> django

---

apache -> mod_wsgi -> django

---

There's also gunicorn which is relatively easier to set up.

Comment: Thanks so much, will look more into these :)

Answer (score 4):

By default, when DEBUG = False in production, django will not serve static files.

### **To change this behavior**

After deploying your application you’ll need to run **`python manage.py collectstatic`** to put all your static files into STATIC_ROOT.

I introduce Whitenoise which allows your web app to serve its own static files. It works with any WSGI-compatible app.

To install it run:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Edit your settings.py file and add WhiteNoise to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list, above all other middleware apart from Django’s SecurityMiddleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

Save and restart your server

Finaly if you want gzip functionality, add this to your settings.py

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

save and restart

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is not entirely true... There's another way! Took me forever to figure out :(

Step 1: If you are/were using them, make sure that all traces of **WhiteNoise** and **django_heroku** are removed: from imports, INSTALLED_APPS, virtual environment, etc.

Step 2:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "path/to/other/static/dir"),
]
```

The key for me was using the proper storage engine which is set by STATICFILES_STORAGE.
You don't need to set STATIC_ROOT because the root will be generated for you by the engine. More on that in the warning section here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT

```
DEBUG = False 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
```

Then finally

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
$ python manage.py runserver
```

If this doesn't help, don't forget logging: [With DEBUG=False, how can I log django exceptions to a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289925/with-debug-false-how-can-i-log-django-exceptions-to-a-log-file)

This kind of helped: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/