# Any way for me to receive DEBUG log/traceback whilst DEBUG is set to FALSE?

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I'm running my live Django server on Digital Ocean so have `DEBUG=FALSE`. Is there any way I can see DEBUG errors? Some function which emails me the traceback or something?

Comment: Found this with a quick search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289925  also check this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Answer (score 0):

Use python logging module 
`import logging` and see django logging topic

see python package called `request_id` from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-request-id