# Django logs location

Tags: django, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django Unhandled Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925898/django-unhandled-exception)

I am using Django, but I am not sure where to find the logs.

Comment: Did you configure `logging`?  Are you using Apache?  Are you using mod_wsgi or mod_python?

Comment: Which version of django? trunk, or 1.1

Comment: Yes, where can I find the log file.

Comment: "Yes"?  Please include your `logging.ini` configuration file so we can find out where your logs are going.

Answer (score 11):

When running the built-in web server, the logs are written to the terminal/console. When running under another web server, Django logs to the server's logs.

Answer (score -5):

This is just like asking "Where are my keys?" For both questions, the answer is: wherever you put them.

Comment: Yes - but where did I put them? You should know. Stop asking me! ;)