# How to print errors in error log in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have example code in view:

try
   bla-bla-bla
  except
    return 500 status

How to view error in this try in error.log for Django ( for example if Django run on mod-python in Apache ) ?

Answer (score 2):

this answer your question:

[Django Unhandled Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925898)

Answer (score 0):

Print to `sys.stderr`, or better yet, use [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).