# Python error in apache error log

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm running Django in apache server but I don't see the actual Python errors being displayed in apache error log file.

In the conf file the level is set to DEBUG.

I see all the print statements but not the actual python error. Any inputs?

This link below provides the solution -

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925898/django-unhandled-exception
```

Comment: Django errors don't usually go to the apache error log, I thought-- don't they default to django-errors.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer basically fixes my problem: [Django Unhandled Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925898/django-unhandled-exception)

I have installed the snippet to get Django exception in the log.